# Intuition for magnetic dipole moment

Tags: electromagnetism, definition, magnetic-moment, dipole-moment

The definition of the electric dipole moment of a system of charges makes sense intuitively -

$$\boldsymbol {\bf p} = \int_{V} \boldsymbol {\bf r} \rho (\boldsymbol {\bf r})dV$$

describes the overall extent to which opposite charges are separated within the system. Larger charges and larger distances between opposite charges results in a bigger dipole moment.

Is there a similar physical interpretation for the MAGNETIC dipole moment? For the definition (in the case of a current carrying circular loop)

$$\boldsymbol {\bf m} = I\int d\boldsymbol {\bf a}$$

$I$ being in there makes since a larger current should make a stronger magnetic field. But why is the  vector area there too? Is there some intuitive reason for this?

$$\boldsymbol {\bf m} = \frac {1}{2}\int_{V} \boldsymbol {\bf r} \times \boldsymbol {\bf J} dV$$

for general volume currents also doesn't make sense (intuitively) to me.

For context, both come from the multipole expansion for the magnetic vector potential. So maybe theres some connection to that...

Answer (score 3):

You can notice that:
$$
\int d^2x = \frac{1}{2}\oint r\times dx \tag{1}
$$
so you can rewrite your original definition as:
$$
m = \frac{1}{2}\oint r\times Idx
$$
From there, the continuous formula is natural.

(1) has a simple geometric interpretation. You are summing the areas of the infinitesimal lateral triangles of a cone whose vertex is the origin and the rim is the loop. Remarkably, the result is independent of the choice of the origin. You can prove it rigorously using the vector version of the Stokes-Kelvin formula:
$$
\oint u\times dx = \int (\nabla \cdot u) d^2x -\int \nabla (u\cdot d^2x)
$$
Applying it to $u=r$, you get:
$$
\begin{align}
\oint u\times dx &= \int 3 d^2x -\int d^2x \\
&= 2\int 3 d^2x\\
\int d^2x &= \frac{1}{2}\oint r\times dx
\end{align}
$$
Note that the $2$ in the $1/2$ refactor is $D-1$ with $D$ the dimension of space which is $3$ in your case.

More in line with electrostatic is to introduce magnetisation:
$$
J = \nabla \times M
$$
You can obtain this formula by noticing that the current distribution of an ideal magnetic dipole is $\nabla\delta\times m$. You can also recover your original definition by integrating the differential relation over a surface:
$$
\int M\cdot d^2x = \oint J\cdot dx
$$
Indeed, you can imagine your loop of currents to be made of dipoles covering a surface whose boundary is the loop.

Now, you want to integrate $M$ over a volume. To express it as $J$, it is natural to integrate it by parts. You use the same result:
$$
2M = (\nabla\cdot r)M-(\nabla r)\cdot M
$$
and you integrate by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
m &= \int M d^3x \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int [(\nabla\cdot r)M-(\nabla r)\cdot M]d^3x \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int [-(r\cdot\nabla) M+(\nabla M)\cdot r]d^3x \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int r\times (\nabla \times M)d^3x \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int r\times Jd^3x
\end{align}
$$
Note that the integration by parts method is cleaner since it gives you an additional boundary term due to surface currents which is omitted in the bulk formula.

This is very relevant in simple physical models. For example, a uniformly magnetised domain has only surface currents. A naive application of your formula would give zero magnetisation. Either you'll need to add the surface current in your current density using Dirac deltas, or use the additional boundary term.

You can motivate the definition of magnetic moment in different ways. The approach given by Semoi is by the torque. You can also approach it by the multipole expansion. In electrostatic, the monopole field is interesting not only because there are some electric monopoles like the electron, but also because it is applicable to any charge distribution (that is not net zero) as long as you are sufficiently far away. The same holds for magnetostatics. However, you don’t have magnetic monopoles, so the next leading order term will be the dipolar term. Working out the math, you’ll find the general formula for dipole moment. Intuitively, you already guess the $r\times J$ form since you want a pseudo vector, it is proportional to $r$ (just like for the electric dipole) and to $J$, so it is pretty much the only candidate left. The tricky part is to correctly guess the $1/2$ pre-factor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That last part certainly did - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To understand why the area appears in the definition, we need to consider a rectangular current carrying wire with side lengths $a$ and $b$  in a magnetic field $B$
[image]
Using **Lorentz's force**, we know that the force $\vec F_1$  is parallel to the $x$-axis, while $\vec F_3$ is anti-parallel to the $x$-axis. Therefore, they cancel each another.

Similarly, we calculate
$ \vec F = \vec F_2  = I \cdot \vec b \times \vec B$ and $\vec F_4=-\vec F$. These two forces possess the same magnitude, and point in opposite direction, but they generate a torque
\begin{align}
M &= 2 \cdot F \cdot  \frac{a}{2} \cdot  \sin(\theta) 
\\
&=2 \cdot (I \cdot b\cdot B) \cdot  \frac{a}{2} \cdot  
\sin(\theta) 
\\
&=I \cdot (a \cdot b) \cdot B \cdot  \sin(\theta) 
\\
&=I \cdot \vec A  \times \vec B
\\
&=\vec \mu_{mag} \times \vec B
\end{align}
where we use $\vec \mu_{mag}  = I \cdot \vec A$. This why we use the area in the definition of the magnetic moment.

Comment: See I know that torque is measured in way, but I still can't see intuitively why area would be there....

Comment: Or is just a quantity that describes the 'rotational tendency' of a loop (or volume) of current? I mean the word 'dipole' generally tries to describe some quantity and it's separation from some point of interest..so is it just that?

Comment: The force acts on the side $b$, because this is where the current is flowing, and the longer the side, the stronger the force. But it also involves the other side $a$, because this is the length of the lever.

Comment: Don't try too hard to make sense of the words. Instead, if you compare the equations for magnetic and electric forces acting on a dipole or the potential energy, there exists a nice symmetry. Thus, the definition makes sense.

Comment: It would be really helpful if there was some nice physical interpretation for the magnetic case like it is for the electrostatic case (i.e. the extent of the separation of opposite charges in a system). m just doesn't feel as tangible to me..what does it mean - physically?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the torque case...that does help with the intuition and I'm completely fine if it is just that. I just want to make sure there isn't some other meaning that I'm missing.

Comment: In physics we are all about the phenomena. So start with those. Take a piece of paper and try to state for the electric case why it does make sense to you to define $d = q r$. Then remember that unlike in the electric case the Lorentz force is perpendicular to the field. Isn't it natural that we have to change something? By the way, the concept that the area is involved is not really important in physics. I mean, I did my phd studying magnetic moments of atoms, but I only used $\vec \mu$. In atoms there is no connection to an area. All that matters is the concept of a magnetic moment.

Comment: I see. I get now why they would't have similar interpretations. So basically you're saying that most quantities are defined the way they are because they come up when trying to investigate some physical phenomenon - not because they are some intrinsic property of that object, am I right?

Comment: Well $d = qr$ makes sense to me because the magnitude of d describes the degree of separation of the two charges - increasing the magnitudes of the charges are taking them farther apart separates them 'more'. But I can see now how that thinking can't be extended to the magnetic case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148579/discussion-between-aadhaar-murty-and-semoi).

Answer (score 0):

The notion of a dipole comes from the fact that there are two "poles" present that have opposite signs. In electrostatics you have two charges of opposite signs, written as $+q$ and $-q$, separated by a small distance. In magnetostatics you have two magnetic monopoles separated by a small distance, called North and South poles. *But wait - surely magnetic monopoles don't exist?* No they don't, but the ends of a bar magnet look like two monopoles and far from the magnet the field has the same spatial dependence as the electric field from an electric dipole.
[image: Diagram showing the dipole fields from two electric charges and a bar magnet]

One way of creating a magnetic dipole is with a current loop and if you define the magnetic dipole moment as $\mathbf m=\frac{1}{2}\int \mathbf r \times \mathbf J dV$ then the formula for the magnetic field from this dipole has the *same form* as the electric field from an electric dipole (see [wikipedia article on dipoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole)). Specifically, the magnetic field at position $\mathbf{r}$ from a magnetic dipole $\mathbf{m}$ is given by

$$
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \frac{3 (\mathbf{m} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}}) \hat{\mathbf{r}} - \mathbf{m}}{r^3}
$$

whereas the electric field at position $\mathbf{r}$ from an electric dipole $\mathbf{p}$ is
$$
\mathbf E(\mathbf r)= \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{3 (\mathbf p \cdot \hat{\mathbf r}) \hat{\mathbf r} - \mathbf p}{r^3}
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf r}$ is the unit vector pointing from the centre of the dipole to the point of observation. In the above formula it is assumed that $|\mathbf r|>0$, otherwise an extra term is required to account for the field "internal" to the dipole.

Although the theory of magnetism in materials is very complex, in essence the magnetic field in a bar magnet arises from a large number of small current loops due to the orbital motion of unpaired electrons. They need to be unpaired otherwise their magnetic moments cancel. In addition, each electron has a "spin" which also looks like a small current loop. All these sources look like magnetic dipoles. Having said that, the correct and detailed study of these fields requires quantum theory ([electron magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment)).